# Gui admin button to make a form have additional features

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface

I created a GUI with a button in PowerShell. If user presses this button a popup window will appear and ask for a password. If the password was `123`, then the GUI should be reloaded with some extra options.
I wrote the following function for this button:

```
Function AdminPanelPass() {
    if ($TextBox91.Text -eq $adminpanelpass) {
        $script:admin = 1
        $form9.Dispose() 
        $script:form.Dispose()
        [void]$script:form.ShowDialog()
    }
}
```

This function is called if the button is pressed. It reads the password from the `TextBox91` on the `form9`. If the password was not `123`, `form9` is closed and after that the main form will be reloaded. Upon reloading the main form there is a check for `$admin`.

The problem is that after the form is closed, it won't open again. The error is:

> Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Form that is
>   already displayed modally cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box.
>   Close the form before calling showDialog."

Can anyone assist please? Is that a correct way to be doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way it works:

```
Function AdminPanelPass(){
    if ($TextBox91.Text -eq $adminpanelpass){
        $script:admin = 1
        $form9.Dispose() 
        $form.Dispose()
        MakeForm
           }
    }
```

MakeForm is the function to create the main form